# How to use valitation and flash message with multiple records in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to build an application to save multiple records in cakephp3.

Now, I realized to create controller and view.
But validation and flash messages does not work.
please tell me how to use validation messages and flash ones.

**Controller:**

```
public function addition5(){
  $this->ViewBuilder()->layout('auth');
  $articles = TableRegistry::get('articles');
  $entities = $articles->newEntities($this->request->data());
  if($this->request->is('post')){
     $articles->connection()->transactional(function () use ($articles, $entities) {
      foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $articles->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]);
      }
    });
   //var_dump($entities);
  }
 $this->set(compact('articles'));
 $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
}
```

**View:**

```
echo $this->Form->create($articles,["class" => "article_form"]);
for($i = 0; $i < 5;$i++){
  $j = $i + 1;
  echo '<h2 class="add5">add articles('.$j.'/5)</h2>';
  echo $this->Form->hidden($i.'.user_id',['value' => h($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id'))]);
  echo $this->Form->input($i.'.title',['label' => 'title','placeholder' => 'title']);
  echo $this->Form->input($i.'.comment',['label' => 'comment','placeholder' => 'comment']);
}
echo $this->Form->button('submit',["class" => "ok"]);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use the validations?? In controller level or model level?

Comment: thank you. I hope  to use the controller level.
I have already been bulit an article system,the system can work.

Comment: Okay, so you can write your logic, before doing any database operations and set flash messages accordingly. But it is always suggested to use the validation rules in Model only!

Comment: Hmm, An article can work. I wrote the code in model.debug($entities) exist error messages.I hope to output the error message in view page.

Comment: Yes Yajin, an article will work, better follow the cakePHP cookbook. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html

Comment: Sorry. I have already read it.